# (JavaScript API 1.3 for Office) Set Value of Custom Properties

Tags: javascript, office-js

My client has decided to migrate to Office 2016 and porting portions of a business process to that client requires us to offer a replacement to the Document Information Panel, which is no longer available. The Backstage file information area isn't considered a sufficient user experience for the users in question, so we're endeavoring to replace the DIP with a Task Pane app.

This example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVGqpns0oT8&feature=share shows that the idea is, at least in theory, possible. We considered buying this app but can't find sufficient information to do so.

So we set about attempting to replicate the functionality we need in the DIP. It appears that we can successfully set Document Properties of standard types, such as strings, which looks something like this:

```
Word.context.run(function(context){
    var properties = context.document.properties;
    context.load(properties):
    return context.sync().then(function(){
        properties.title = properties.title + " Additional Title Text"; // once the sync goes off, this works.
        return context.sync();
    });    
});
```

However, when we try to update an Document Property that's, for example, a Managed Metadata property defined by a SharePoint content type, the value in the proxy object loads and remains changed, but it seems to break its relationship to the actual document property. The code below demonstrates:

```
Word.context.run(function(context){
    var properties = context.document.properties;
    var customProperties = properties.customProperties;
    context.load(properties):
    context.load(customProperties);
    return context.sync().then(function(){
        var managedMetadataProperty = customProperties.getItem('MngdMetadata');
        properties.title = properties.title + " Additional Title Text"; // once the sync goes off, this works.
        context.load(managedMetadataProperty);
        return context.sync().then(function(){
            console.log(managedMetadataProperty.value) // let's say this looks like "10;#Label 1|64d2cd3d-57d4-4c23-9603-866d54ee74f1"
            managedMetadataProperty.value = "11;#Label 2|cc3d57d4-4c23-72d4-3031-238b9100f52g"
            return context.sync();  // now the value in the javascript object for managedMetadataProperty is updated, but the value in the document does not change. 
        });
    });    
});
```

The document property Managed Metadata Property never changes in the Word UI, nor does a change push back to the SharePoint. Say we save and close the document after making the update, then re-open it. The Property value has not visibly changed, however when we load the proxy object with 'context.load()', the value that's available reflects the changes we made on last run.

I'm unclear about why this would be. It seems like to circumvent this, I would need to make a call back to SharePoint to update the relevant field, but I don't know how I would instruct Word to refresh with the new information from SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a great question. 
The custom properties API gives you access to some built-in properties as well as custom properties. SP-related properties do NOT follow in this category from the API perspective. (and the same is true in VBA/VSTO/COM) To access those you need to use the CustomXmlParts functionalities. [Here is a good example](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-Work-with-custom-XML-parts/blob/master/C%23/CustomXMLAppWeb/App/Home/Home.js) on how to use it in the Javascript API.

Also, FYI, the team is working right now in a feature to enable the DIP again, i don't have concrete dates or commitment, but you might get this functionality again out of the box soon.

Comment: That's great to know. I'll take a look. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would ask, though, how would I go about determining the NameSpace or ID of the properties? Would the information defined in the ContentType be the same in an instance of the document? 

Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: You go a get this namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/metadata/properties

Comment: Yeah, found my way there. 

General piece of advice, if you need to explore these properties, copy your target word document, convert the file extension to *.zip, then navigate through the customXml folder. Therein, you'll find all the different definitions that you could theoretically access.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **customPropertyCollectionObject.add(key, value)** ?

It will replace existing kvp's in the customPropertiesCollectionObject.

Here is the documentation [customPropertiesCollection](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/custompropertycollection)